# Webtoon manga where the MC has a disease that ages him rapidly and blackmails a doctor

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

Basically in this webtoon manga there is this kid who is kindergarten age, but he has a disease that ages him rapidly to the point he looks like a teenager. He is a famous gamer, like a rich pro gamer.

He blackmails this famous doctor by telling the world he plays VR games as a girl (like *Sword Art Online* type games) and has him do a check up on him. The doctor tells the MC that he has a few years left to live as his disease is accelerating more and more. The kid decides to spend the last few moments with his one and only child hood friend.

Now keep in mind that while he looks like a teen or so, he is technically like 5 or 6, kindergarten age. So his friend is that young too and his friend's parents had her cut him off so that she would not be bulled since he looks so much older then her despite being the same age.

He bribes the school for his ex childhood friend to be in her class to be with her till he dies. Now I'm not sure if this is a slice of life or a romance, as I think he wanted to confess to her (cause remember he ages quickly so he has the mind and body of a teen, but his heart is still of that of a young child). I don't know when it started, but I think I read this in like 2012 or 2011.